# django error: unexpected keyword argument 'widget'

Tags: django-forms

I want to display a field (named 'icon') as radio button.

I created method callback in order to display DateTimeFields with JQuery. The code following should do it, however i get this error when i run my server:

Error when calling the metaclass bases
    make_custom_datefield() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widget'

...

Exception Location: Virtualenvs/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py in fields_for_model, line 164

forms.py:

```
def make_custom_datefield(f):
    formfield = f.formfield()
    if isinstance(f, DateTimeField):
        formfield.widget.format = '%m/%d/%Y'
        formfield.widget.attrs.update({'class':'datetimePicker', 'readonly':'true'})
    return formfield

class FlashForm(forms.ModelForm):
    formfield_callback = make_custom_datefield

    class Meta:
        model = Flash
        exclude=('user','marker','address')
        widgets = {'icon': forms.RadioSelect(), }
```

Can you please help me, i have really no clue how to solve this !

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Eventually, i found the answer: i had to add  **kwargs parameter.

```
def make_custom_datefield(f,**kwargs):
    formfield = f.formfield(**kwargs)
    if isinstance(f, DateTimeField):
        formfield.widget.format = '%m/%d/%Y'
        formfield.widget.attrs.update({'class':'datetimePicker', 'readonly':'true'})
    return formfield
```